# Impossible to connect to mongo after server shutdown

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am running a mongo cluster (v 3.4.1) on a remote Ubuntu server. This server had an unexpected shutdown yesterday. Since that, I cannot connect to mongo.

I connected by ssh to the server to check if mongo was running. It seems to be the case because if I use the mongo command, I get the following output:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.1
Server has startup warnings: 
2017-09-28T08:01:43.906+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-28T08:01:43.906+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2017-09-28T08:01:43.906+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2017-09-28T08:01:44.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-09-28T08:01:44.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-09-28T08:01:44.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-09-28T08:01:44.204+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
```

Now if I run "mongod" I get the exception:

```
...
2017-09-28T10:10:26.065+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2017-09-28T10:10:26.065+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
...
```

I tried in sudo mode, I got:

```
...
2017-09-28T10:12:21.857+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2017-09-28T10:12:21.857+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2017-09-28T10:12:21.857+0200 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2017-09-28T10:12:21.857+0200 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: InternalError: Failed to set up sockets
2017-09-28T10:12:21.857+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
...
```

Which would mean that an instance of mongo is already running...

Then I tried to kill mongo process, either with `sudo service mongod stop` or `sudo pkill mongod` or `sudo kill <PID>` after listing processes with `ps -ef | grep mongo`. But the process does not disappear from the list (seems that it restarts immediately).

So if I try to run `sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair` (there is a mongod.lock file in the directory), I still get the error "Address already in use".

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I've deleted my answer as you've altered the question, have you tried killing it via the port number?

Comment: If I try to display the processes listening at 27017 with "netstat -tulnap | grep 27017", it returns one line: "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -  ". What should I do next ?

Comment: EDIT: I'm not familiar with netstat options, but if I use -ap or -lpn instead of -tulnap I get "tcp        0      0 localhost:27017         *:*                     LISTEN      17636/docker-proxy". I'll check why docker is using that port...

Comment: Try lsof -i :<portnumber> ie  'lsof -i :27017'  and see what it outputs

Comment: lsof does not exist on that distribution, but I partially solved the problem: there is indeed a dockerized mongodb on that server, what I didn't know, and it seems to work well but it cannot be accessed from the outside since the server reboot... Thanks for your help anyway.